# Hibernate and N+1 Query

Tags: hibernate

I am confusing about n+1 concept, I understand it's just used for retriving data (select clause). But if I have many entities then I loop them and call update statement for each element. Is it called N+1 ?

In addition, Hibernate saveOrUpdateAll(..) will loop through all elements and generate query, what is the best practice for large input ?

Thank you for your help

I try to research on the internet about the concept but I am still not clear in case update or delete query

Answer (score 0):

The N+1 phenomenon corresponds usually to the fact that hibernate may do one query per element belonging to a list of N elements previously retrieved by a first query. The N+1 queries phenomenon may produce bad performances and has to be mitigated with various strategies implying joins most of the time.

If you have several objects to update with no common logic between the changes, there  is no way avoid triggering one update query per object.
If there is a common logic, e.g. set the same value to one attribute of all the objects, you can make a batch update, i.e execute one query to update all the objects in one go.